# FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: EnsureLocalCapacity (FileInputStream.open0, android.graphics.Typeface.getFullFlipFont)

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, crash

After upgrading BuildTools from 23 to 27 I faced issue with crash.

I've checked RAM usage in profiler - there's no anomaly there. App crashes sometimes in background, sometimes in foreground, in different activities (crash is completely nondeterministic), it doesn't seem to depend on memory usage (was able to crash with 350mb usage like also with 200mb)

I also installed 'square/leakcanary' to find any memoryleaks, but nothing's there...

Seems to be a problem with loading native typeface. I don't use custom font in this application. I managed to crash app on Samsung S9 and Samsung S5. Any ideas? :(

Thanks for any help!

Stacktrace:

```
2018-10-05 08:09:04.740 20542-20542/pl.chillout.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pl.chillout.debug, PID: 20542
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: EnsureLocalCapacity
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.getFullFlipFont(Typeface.java:1275)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.getFontPathFlipFont(Typeface.java:1220)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.SetFlipFonts(Typeface.java:1413)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.SetAppTypeFace(Typeface.java:1547)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1020)
    at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.onCreate(SupportActivity.java:66)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:321)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
    at pl.chillout.redesign.activity.BaseDrawerActivity.onCreate(BaseDrawerActivity.java:45)
    at pl.chillout.redesign.activity.ChilloutActivity.onCreate(ChilloutActivity.java:115)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I just caught the same crash on Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: If your pc is with x64 operating system, can u please check if the project is NOT saved under Program Files x86? If so, please cut and paste it elsewhere like Program Files or your desktop and try again.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: with a high probability it is not a hardware failure

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - This is Android.  See the tags.  See the stacktrace!

Comment: @AbdulAziz, what code? There is no specific failing fragment, and I cannot post whole application source code (and I guess it'll probably won't help you).

Comment: @Cililing so could you publish complete stacktrace for this error? I guess you have more records in the stacktrace. Also you can publish specific fragment where you work with ttf fonts

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I'm having the same issue in a S9.

Comment: Actually I didn't found any solution, but in release build I haven't managed crash app because of it

Comment: I've seen this happening with profiler been attached only. Might be the bug with profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I finally managed to fully "fix" this crash (as I mentioned in question comment section problem wasn't applicable to release builds) by upgrading BuildTools from version 27 to 28.

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer.
I just removed this issue by upgrading to build tools 30 (don't know my previously installed version)

Answer (score 0):

See if explicitly specifying default font in all your views fixes the issue. It looks like it's trying to load a font that doesn't exist.

```
 <TextView
  .....
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
```

Comment: Why do you think so? Crash is not deterministic, and existance of font is.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you create, recreate, or use a TextView only under certain circumstances. That may explain why the crash occurs during onCreate. FWITW, you can find similar bugs in any app if you turn on StrictMode and simply call onCreate. If you are not getting error often, you may consider ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this situation ***maybe*** you are using static objects like that :

```
private static TextView textView; //DO NOT DO THIS
private static Context context; //DO NOT DO THIS
```

**this is the first sign of a memory leak.**

Unfortunately there is no full code

Comment: No, I've looked for memory leaks before I wrote this question.

Answer (score 0):

Dear add largeheap=true in manifest. then finish started activities. And check your drawable dimension (size). I faced this issue in PagerView. I resize drawable images. and finish all activity. and largheap now crash is removed. I think your error related to orio devices please initialize all objects for orio devices.